Verbose Logback logging
We have updated one of our services to the latest spring version. Since then we have the following verbose logging
09:30:10,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Here is a list of configurators discovered as a service, by rank: 
09:30:10,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 -   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator
09:30:10,622 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - They will be invoked in order until ExecutionStatus.DO_NOT_INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY is returned.
09:30:10,623 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Constructed configurator of type class org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator
09:30:10,638 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.RootLogLevelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 3 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
09:30:10,639 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
09:30:10,640 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator
09:30:10,655 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.scmo]
09:30:10,658 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.scmo]
09:30:10,658 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.SerializedModelConfigurator.configure() call lasted 18 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
09:30:10,658 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
09:30:10,662 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator
09:30:10,669 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:30:10,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
09:30:10,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure() call lasted 9 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=INVOKE_NEXT_IF_ANY
09:30:10,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Trying to configure with ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator
09:30:10,683 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - Constructed configurator of type class ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator
09:30:10,683 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator@4f071df8 - Setting up default configuration.
09:30:10,743 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer@62fe6067 - ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator.configure() call lasted 60 milliseconds. ExecutionStatus=NEUTRAL
09:30:12,580 |-INFO in ConfigurationWatchList(mainURL=jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback-spring.xml, fileWatchList={}, urlWatchList=[}) - URL [jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback-spring.xml] is not of type f
ile
09:30:12,972 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@47404bea - Adding [jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml] to configuration watch list.
09:30:12,972 |-INFO in ConfigurationWatchList(mainURL=jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback-spring.xml, fileWatchList={}, urlWatchList=[}) - Cannot watch [jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/org/spring
framework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml] as its protocol is not one of file, http or https.
09:30:12,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ConversionRuleModelHandler - registering conversion word applicationName with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ApplicationNameConverter]
09:30:12,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ConversionRuleModelHandler - registering conversion word clr with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter]
09:30:12,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ConversionRuleModelHandler - registering conversion word correlationId with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.CorrelationIdConverter]
09:30:12,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ConversionRuleModelHandler - registering conversion word wex with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter]
09:30:12,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ConversionRuleModelHandler - registering conversion word wEx with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter]
09:30:13,001 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(16){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr(%applicationName[%15.15t]){faint} %clr(){faint}%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr(%applicationName[%15.15t]){faint} %clr(${LOG_CORRELATION_PATTERN:-}){faint}%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"
09:30:13,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "UTF-8" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET:-${file.encoding:-UTF-8}}"
09:30:13,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "TRACE" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD:-TRACE}"
09:30:13,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %5p 16 --- %applicationName[%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx" substituted for "${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- %applicationName[%t] ${LOG_CORRELATION_PATTERN:-}%-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"
09:30:13,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "UTF-8" substituted for "${FILE_LOG_CHARSET:-${file.encoding:-UTF-8}}"
09:30:13,002 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "TRACE" substituted for "${FILE_LOG_THRESHOLD:-TRACE}"
09:30:13,003 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@47404bea - Adding [jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml] to configuration watch list.
09:30:13,003 |-INFO in ConfigurationWatchList(mainURL=jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/logback-spring.xml, fileWatchList={}, urlWatchList=[}) - Cannot watch [jar:nested:/app/vpp-account-service.jar/!BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.3.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml] as its protocol is not one of file, http or https.
09:30:13,023 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Missing watchable .xml or .properties files.
09:30:13,023 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Watching .xml files requires that the main configuration file is reachable as a URL
09:30:13,029 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory] to ERROR
09:30:13,032 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase] to ERROR
09:30:13,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] to WARN
09:30:13,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils] to WARN
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool] to WARN
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] to ERROR
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] to WARN
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx] to WARN
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [CONSOLE]
09:30:13,034 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:30:13,059 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "TRACE" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD}"
09:30:13,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:30:13,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(16){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr(%applicationName[%15.15t]){faint} %clr(){faint}%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}"
09:30:13,070 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ModelInterpretationContext@305f7627 - value "UTF-8" substituted for "${CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET}"
09:30:13,151 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.LoggerModelHandler - Setting level of logger [com.aoe.congo.vpp.accountservice] to TRACE
09:30:13,151 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@5d018107 - Propagating TRACE level on Logger[com.aoe.congo.vpp.accountservice] onto the JUL framework
09:30:13,151 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.RootLoggerModelHandler - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO

Not sure what causes this but I have no idea how to solve this. It is a simple spring boot ms with default logging configuration.
We are using the latest spring boot version 3.3.5 with the default spring logback configuration. We are running our service inside a docker container. The base image of this container is eclipse-temurin:21-jre.
(I know this is the default logback behavior to be that verbose if there is a warning/error. But I do not know why we have this warning or how to get rid of it...)

You get this output on startup because there were warnings or errors in the logback initialization process: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting
These are the two warnings in the log output:
09:30:13,023 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Missing watchable .xml or .properties files.
09:30:13,023 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.model.processor.ConfigurationModelHandlerFull - Watching .xml files requires that the main configuration file is reachable as a URL

Maybe you configured logback to monitor the jar-embedded logback.xml file for changes or the logback is not readable at all? https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan

As I said I know why logback dumps its configuration. I just could not figure out why as I was using the standard spring configuration. I added a logback-spring.xml and added my own configuration. Now its gone as I am not using autoScan. Thank you

Oh yes, sorry, I missed your edit. But it must be connected to autoscanning the config file, because that's where the error message comes from (see source code).
